# php-cgi shows mysql modules but throws "Call to undefined function mysql_connect()" error

Tags: mysql, php, php-cgi

I have compiled PHP 5.3.6 from source on Mac OS X 10.6 using the --with-mysqli=mysqlnd option. The output of both php -m and php-cgi -m show the mysqli and mysqlnd modules. When I run a simple test PHP file containing a mysql_connect(...) using the regular php binary, it connects fine. When I use the same test PHP file with php-cgi, I get:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined
>   function mysql_connect() in
>   /Users/chris/test2.php on line 2

I've confirmed that the MySQL socket information is correct in php.ini and have ensured that php-cgi is using that file using the -c argument. MySQL works fine using the regular mysql command line interface and obviously is working with regular PHP. phpinfo() from php-cgi shows correct versions of mysqli & mysqlnd libraries.

I need to run PHP in a CGI configuration in this particular environment so I really need php-cgi to work. I am not worried about Apache2/nginx/etc at this point - just getting CGI to work. Any advice on what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have compiled PHP with support of **mysqli** extension (mysqli_* functions)... but the error clearly shows that you are using `mysql_connect()` function (without "i", which belongs to **mysql** extension). These are 2 different extensions: `mysqli` stands for "MySQL Improved" and is preferred to use over older and less feature-rich `mysql`.

You have 2 choices:

1) Update your code to use `mysqli_*` functions

2) Compile your PHP again with `mysql` extension support (do not forget to enable it later in php.ini)

**P.S.** In any case I would recommend to use PDO for your database needs (if you can, of course).

Comment: That did it. Thanks for the solution and providing some options.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try this:

In file php.ini has been uncommented extension mysql.so?
or try con this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516739/how-to-add-mysql-support-for-php-using-macports)

I hope it solves your problem.